# ZSH History Configuration

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, zsh

i want configure my zsh history commands on linux with the next format:

```
2020-12-21 23:59:59 | user | 192.168.10.15 | command
```

When:

```
2020-12-21 23:59:59 --> date time when the command was executed
user --> username
192.168.10.15 --> ip from de ssh client
command --> command executed
```

I want save this on, .zsh_history. Please help me.
Thx.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Try asking on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: The history file is primarily meant for `zsh` itself to consume, not the user. It's not that configurable. You can use `EXTENDED_HISTORY` to add the starting time and the elapsed time, but that's it.